# Get display name for App Ids in Azure conditional access policies

Tags: azure, powershell, charts, azure-active-directory

Getting all the CA policies using,

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/conditionalAccess/policies"
$response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $CustomHeader -OutputType PSObject
```

Property, for example,

```
$response.value[0].conditions.applications.includeApplications
```

list App Id, not the App display name.

```
Get-MgApplication -all
```

Only returns custom applications and not Azure default Apps.
Found this link,
https://github.com/emilyvanputten/Microsoft-Owned-Enterprise-Applications/blob/main/Microsoft%20Owned%20Enterprise%20Applications%20Overview.md
Helpful but not complete.

Any ideas on how to get the Azure default app list using Graph or (Azure) PowerShell module?

Thanks ...

Comment: Try calling `Get-MgApplication` against each app id individually, eg.: `$response.value[0].conditions.applications.includeApplications |ForEach-Object {Get-MgApplication -ApplicationId $_}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have few conditional access policies that included with **applications** like this:

[image]

To get these **display names** for App IDs in all Azure Conditional Access policies, you can make use of below sample PowerShell script:

```
$uri = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/identity/conditionalAccess/policies"
$response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest -Uri $uri -Method GET -Headers $CustomHeader -OutputType PSObject
$AppIds = @()

# Iterate through each policy to extract application IDs
foreach ($policy in $response.value) {
    $applicationIds = $policy.conditions.applications.includeApplications
    $AppIds += $applicationIds | Where-Object { $_ -notin $AppIds }
}

$output = @()

foreach ($appId in $AppIds) {

    $servicePrincipals = Get-MgServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$appId'"
    foreach ($sp in $servicePrincipals) {
        $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Application DisplayName' = $sp.displayName
            'AppId' = $sp.appId
        }
    }
}

$output | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/app-objects-and-service-principals?tabs=azure-powershell
gets easier when you know your basics …

Thanks Sridevi for the help .. :)